# EF6 lost relationship between enitites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my MVC4, EF6 application i'm creating a "Contact" object. this Contact holds an "Address" object.
both instances are created on the same view.
this is how i do this on the controller side:

[image]

i can see it creates both instances just fine when i take a look at my Db.
Here's how it looks:

Address Table:

[image]

Contacts Table:

[image]

It all works great until i restart my application. this action cause the relationship between my Contact and its Address to dissapear.
This is how it looks on my second run:
[image]

Here's my Address class:

[image]

And my Contact class:

[image]

any idea why is this happening ? Thx.

Comment: Can we see your `Contacts`/`Address` classes/mapping? It sounds like the relevant properties aren't being lazily loaded. You may need to declare a property virtual, or explicitly load the related entities, depending on what your classes look like.

Comment: Sure. take a look at the edited question. Thx.

Comment: the virtual keyword allows Entity Framework to "defer" loading of navigation properties until they are accessed.  Navigation properties are usually not returned until they are actually accessed.  Are you finding that the properties are missing when you access them, or did you just check at that specific break point after the first database query?

Comment: They are actually missing. this action result directs to a view of all contacts. in this view we'll see each contact with his address. in this specific contact instance there will be no Address.

Comment: When your application is restarted, does the relation still exist in your DB?

Comment: My App restarts when i want it to restart (just stop debugging and starts again). the relation is still there in the DB as you can see in my pic. the thing is that if i will create a new instance, the relation will work just fine. but once the app is closed and then reopen, the relation is gone (not on DB).

Comment: By the way, you're defeating the whole purpose of `UnitOfWork` by calling `Save()` on each entity separately.

Comment: That was an act of desperation..

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're creating a new `Address` in your `Contact` constructor.

Try this instead:

```
public Contact()
{
      FirstName = String.Empty;
      LastName = String.Empty;
      //Address = new Address(); <-- remove this line
}
```

Alternatively, use `Include` to 'Eager-Load' `Address` so you won't have to rely on the Proxy to 'Lazy-Load' `Address` for you.

**Edit:**

I believe you're initializing `Address` because you want to make sure it is always set so you'll never get a `NullReferenceException` thrown at you. for that, you can try this:

```
 private Address _address;

 public virtual Address Address
 {
      get { return _address ?? (_address = new Address()); }
      set { _address = value; }
 }
```

Comment: Can u please explain the "Include" and what exactly is it?

Comment: Since you're abstracting the Entity Framework context using Repository pattern i guess you don't have direct access to the `Include` method. yet, in the implementation of `ContactRepository.GetById(id)` method you can call it. something like: `return this.Contacts.Include(x => x.Address).Single(x => x.Id == id);`

Comment: The `Include` method is intended to 'eager-load' related data, instead of 'lazy-load' which means the context will query the database for `Address` data only upon accessing it's navigation property. In SQL terms it's simply mean that the initial SQL statement will already contain the necessary `JOIN` clause for the `ContactAddress` table (or whatever you actually named it).

Comment: Thx.
I'm checking this solution as we speak.

Comment: I did Exactly what u said. now i getting a DbUpdateException with the following innerException: "The column name 'Address_ID' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'Address_ID' may appear twice in the view definition." Please, HELP.

Comment: What exactly did you do? did you remove `Address = new Address();` from the `Contact` constructor?

Comment: sure. and also changed the property to private with get/set implementation (from your example).

Comment: Try to add to one Repository only: `unitOfWork.ContactRepository.Add(contact);`

Comment: Also, for now just remove the line from the constructor, don't do the private backing-field yet. so we can pinpoint the problem more easily.

Comment: ok. i had some terrible migration trouble but now it looks like the relationship is saved(!). This is just by not setting a new Addrerss() on the Contact constructor. but, how can i avoid NullReferenceException to be thrown like this?

Comment: Now try the backing-field solution and see what's happening.